# Aftermarket Pneumatic Suspension - Pro's and Con's

Tags: vw, suspension, aftermarket-upgrade, chassis

I am trying to estimate the feasibility of installing an after market pneumatic suspension (called sometimes air bags suspension?) for a VW Tiguan. The Touareg, for example, has a factory optional equipment of this kind.

The purpose for this project would be not to lower the car in order to improve high speed maneuverability but to be able to raise the car when going through tough roads and then getting back to a given height. Optionally lower the car a bit as a default position so high speed maneuverability would be improved a little.

I am not even informed enough to conduct searches on the internet, what keywords to look for and so on.

Ideally I would find a kit.  In order to better understand a pneumatic suspension I would like to know the benefits of using this type of a system in my vehicle.

***Will installing a pneumatic suspension damage my vehicle?***

***What are the pro's and con's to pneumatic suspensions?***

***Could people point me to a resource where I can find out more on this?***

Comment: Rather than asking "what to shop for", consider rewording the question to be more about technical facts, like "What are the components of an airbag suspension setup".  That would give you the info you need and be a better fit for our question format.

Comment: Since shopping advice is out of scope on the site I have changed your question around a bit to be more informative.  It sounds like you need an education on these suspensions, once you are educated then you can shop  for them.  If you do not like my edits you can roll them back but your question would get closed.  Hope this is helpful to you.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will installing a pneumatic suspension damage my vehicle?

Not necessary depending on the kit.  Per your vehicle a company called [Air Lift](https://www.airliftperformance.com/blog/plush-automotive-project-soccer-mom-vw-tiguan/) does make an air ride lowering kit for your vehicle that has air bags for the rear that would simply replace the spring:

[image]

and air struts for the front that will replace the coilovers:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The issue you would face is if you were to install an air strut, would you need to trim the spring pocket to allow the bag to sit in because you cannot have it rub.  Sometimes it is a simply swap and replace so if you were to ever sell your vehicle you could remove the air system if you wanted.

> What are the pro's and con's to pneumatic suspensions?

### PROS:

- Better ride quality
- Better handling

### CONS:

- Additional maintenance will be required
- Possibility of blown air bag/strut
- Lines will have to be checked at scheduled intervals
- Typically good practice to oil the system
- Increased noise (compressor & valves)
- You will have to find a speciality shop that can align your vehicle.

> Could people point me to a resource where I can find out more on this?

Per your question I am unfamiliar of a lifted air suspension for your vehicle.  I've seen a lowered air suspension but that isn't what you're after.  You could always look at purchasing a totaled Touareg suspension or purchasing the struts and air bags for the rear and building your own air management system.  As far as the fabrication goes you could consult with an off road company or consult your local Volkswagen dealer for the air struts/bags.  You could always reference online auction stores like ebay for the struts/bags.

Fabrication of a system can be extremely costly if you're not capable of doing it yourself.  Even the air ride lowering system alone starts off around two thousand US dollars and that's not including install time.  That type of system will set you back so I would encourage possibly looking into a mild lift kit by replacing the springs that will assist in adding around 1" more lift for around two hundred US dollars plus whatever the install would be.

Example [springs](https://www.ecstuning.com/ES248705/?gclid=CLe7reHwoswCFdcYgQodqfsCJQ):

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely clear if the kit presented in the answer can raise the car or not, since that was my main desire in this research..

Comment: A lowering air ride has been known to be able to raise the vehicle higher then stock but I dont have a stock ride height and air ride height measurement to be able to validate that.